# WHERE AND OR issue to get the checked items

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to create a dynamic query that joins my tables and filters the filters selected.  In my example, the products_bind_filters are the filter items that belong to each product.

I'm trying to find the products that have the following criteria as an example in one result:

- Products that are Red, Green OR Blue
- that are also available in Small or Medium

My query is:

```
SELECT *,
            p.name as productName,
            c.name as categoryName,
            p.price as productPrice,
            p.hookName as productHook,
            c.hookName as categoryHook,
            p.imageMain as productThumb
            FROM products p
            JOIN products_bind_category pbc ON pbc.productsId = p.productsId
            JOIN category c ON pbc.categoryId = c.categoryId
            JOIN products_bind_value pbv ON pbv.productsId = p.productsId
            WHERE p.productsId != '0'
            AND pbc.categoryId = '10'
             AND (pbv.valueId = '54' ) AND (pbv.valueId = '167' OR pbv.valueId = '186' OR pbv.valueId = '175' )
            GROUP BY p.productsId
            ORDER BY p.Price ASC
```

However, it's not returning the correct results.  There are products that match the criteria but it's not showing them.

Any ideas?

I did try use an IN query but it also didn't work.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: No `GROUP BY` query that began `SELECT *` ever ended well.

Comment: (pbv.valueId = '54' ) AND (pbv.valueId = '167' OR pbv.valueId = '186' OR pbv.valueId = '175' ) can never be true.

Comment: I can guess that Red, Green OR Blue are pbv.valueId = '167' OR pbv.valueId = '186' OR pbv.valueId = '175' but what is  Small or Medium

Comment: why is this voted down?

Comment: Why is it voted up?

Comment: Yes, I see by the replies what I was doing wrong now.  Feel a bit stupid now.

Comment: Your request shouldn't have been downvoted, though, (especially without saying why) because you explained your problem and showed your query. It shouldn't have been upvoted either, because it is somewhat incomplete without any sample data. Had you shown some sample table rows, your problem (key/values) would have become much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with a key/value table, which is always kind of hard.

This condition:

```
AND (pbv.valueId = '54')
AND (pbv.valueId = '167' OR pbv.valueId = '186' OR pbv.valueId = '175')
```

is never met, because no row in the table can have a value of 54 and not 54 at the same time.

One way to deal with key/values is aggregation:

```
select *
from products p
join products_bind_category pbc on pbc.productsid = p.productsid
join category c on pbc.categoryid = c.categoryid
where p.productsid in
(
  select productsid
  from products_bind_value
  group by productsid
  having sum(valueid = 54) > 0
     and sum(valueid in (167, 196, 175)) > 0
)
order by p.productsid;
```

The `SUM(<expression>) > 0)` uses the fact that in MySQL true = 1, false = 0 by the way.

Comment: Good idea, will try this.

Comment: Just tried this, seems to work fine.  Thanks for the help.